# Connect Bidet with 1/2 inch supply line to 3/8 toilet line

Tags: toilet, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures, connectors

Bought a bidet with 1/2 inch Supply line

[image: Bidet 1/2 inch supply line]
I need to connect it with Toilet which has 3/8 inch line

[image: 3/8 inch line]

I assume I need a Tee to connect it. But need help as it wouldn't be a regular 3/8 or 1/2 inch Tee. Probably need a 3/8 to 1/2 inch adapter.

Confused!! Need help.

Comment: Yep. Your local hardware store has entire walls of this type of thing. Have you checked?

Comment: They have 3/8 Tee's. But none of them able to find a 3/8 F to 1/2 M inch adapter. I wonder if I am thinking it all wrong. May be a better alternative?

Comment: Maybe look for a supply line that does the conversion.

Comment: I suspect.... perhaps you do not reallllly want to convert from 3/8 to 1/2? If the bidet has 1/2" connection, it probably wants the pressure associated with a 1/2" supply. Go 3/8" and you will not get the performance the unit was designed for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ordinary 3/8 tee, with a 3/8 outlet on the side and then add a supply line that has 3/8 on that end and 1/2 on the end attached to the bidet.  Here's a link to one example:
[Brasscraft 3/8 to 1/2 inch FIP faucet connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004ZH9M2Q)

Comment: Or a valve that has 2ea 3/8" ports with the supply line you linked to would work, I don't like having T's just more places to leak.